# Salesforce connector missing from Logic App Standard in vscode?

Tags: salesforce, azure-logic-apps

I'm developing a Logic App (Standard, Stateful) using VSCode for local development but I cannot find the Salesforce connector in the actions flyout:

[image]

If I look at all the connectors available, in alphabetical order, you can see Salesforce is not there:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Went through the MS docs on the connector but I'm not seeing any notes about why this may be the case and I can certainly see the Salesforce connector in Azure if I develop the logic app in the browser. I can confirm the Salesforce connector can be found in both Stateful and Stateless workflows in a Standard logic app in the browser, just not visible when doing local dev in vscode.

Comment: Are you using Azure connectors or you skipped![image](https://i.imgur.com/8AdLuuJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

Tried to repro in My Machine, Salesforce connector was available in VS code as below:

[image]

Make sure you are selecting "**Use connectors from Azure"**

[image]

It was not available when tried to look in alphabetical order as below:

[image]

When searched by name, it was available(unselected **"Group by connector"**) as below:

[image]